# Search and replace option element in string JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, search, replace

I have the next string variable which contains the next string

```
var content = '<div id="TypeModifiedProduct" class="form-group WSUage2">
  <label for="TypeModified">Type</label>
  <span class="pull-right alignText" style="margin-right: 40%;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UseTypeModified" name="UseTypeModified" > Use option
  </span>
  <select name="TypeModified" id="TypeModified" class="form-control" style="width:40%" >
    <option value="Maintenance - Stand Alone form" >Maintenance - Stand Alone form</option>
    <option value="Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form">Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form</option>
  </select>
</div>';
```

Now I want for example search for the second option

```
<option value="Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form">Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form</option>
```

And change it for beign selected option

```
<option value="Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form" selected >Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form</option>
```

Then finally return this new string with the change in the option element.

Thanks in advice

Comment: Try `var $div = $('<div />',{html: content});
$div.find('option[value="Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

content = $div.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a string as the result

```
var $div = $('<div />',{html: content});
$div.find('option[value="Maintenance Plus - Stand Alone form"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

content = $div.html();

console.log(content)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DNB6f/1/)

Comment: Thanks to all for your help, now i want the full text included the option selected, Arun thanks but i need the whole text with the change you did in the fiddle

Comment: @martinezjc since we are assigning `content = $div.html();`, `content` will have the modified text

Comment: Sorry i didn't saw the whole console Arun, thanks a lot to everyone for your answers!